# Is that "$\mathsf{T}:\mathsf{V}\to\mathsf{W}$ be linear" necessary in the definition of a transformation is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, definition, inverse-function

**Definition.** *Let $\mathsf{V}$ and $\mathsf{W}$ be vector spaces, and let  $\mathsf{T}:\mathsf{V}\to\mathsf{W}$ be linear. A function $\mathsf{U}:\mathsf{W}\to\mathsf{V}$ is said to be an **inverse** of $\mathsf{T}$ if $\mathsf{TU}=\mathsf{I_W}$ and $\mathsf{UT}=\mathsf{I_V}$. If $\mathsf T$ has an inverse, then $\mathsf T$ is said to be **invertible**. If $\mathsf T$ is invertible, then the inverse of $\mathsf T$ is unique and is denoted by $\mathsf T^{-1}$.*

---

Given the definition of invertible and inverse of linear transformation above, my question is that is $\ $ "$\mathsf{T}:\mathsf{V}\to\mathsf{W}$ be linear" a necessary condition for a transformation, which may not be linear, being invertible? Or it's just because it's the only concern here (since it's linear algebra)?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the inverse of a function between sets?

Comment: No, it is not necessary that a transformation to be "linear" in order that it have an inverse.  For example, the transformation $f(x)= x^3$ from R to R is given by $f^{-1}(x)= \sqrt[3]{x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because the context here is linear algebra. For instance, $c\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $c(x)=x^3$ is not linear, but it is invertible; its inverse is $x\mapsto\sqrt[3]x$.